# Is there a way to read messages using Kafka stream(not via KafkaConsumer) from beginning everytime in java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

We are creating a POC to read database CDC and push it to external systems.

1. each source table CDC are sent to respective topics in Avro format(with Kafka Schema Registry and Kafka Server)
2. We are writing java code to consume the messages in avro schema,de-serialize it using AvroSerde and join them and then send to different topics so that it can be consumed by external systems.

We have a limitation though that we cannot produce messages to source table topics to send/receive new contents/changes. So only way to write join code is to read messages from beginning everytime from every source topic when we run the application.(until we have confident that code is working and can start receiving live data again)

In KafkaConsumer object we have an option to use seekToBeginning method to force reading from beginning in jave code, which works. However there are no option when we try to stream topic using KStream object and force to read it from beginning. What are the alternatives here?

We tried to reset the offset using kafka-consumer-groups reset-topic with --to-earliest but that sets the offset only to the nearest . When we try to reset offset manually with "0" with --to-offset parameter we get below warning but does not set to "0". my understanding is, setting to 0 should read messages from beginning. correct me if I am wrong.

"WARN New offset (0) is lower than earliest offset for topic partition"

Sample code below

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVER);
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, GROUP_ID);
properties.put("schema.registry.url", SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL);
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, APPLICATION_ID);

StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
//nothing returned here, when some offset has already been set
KStream myStream = builder.stream("my-topic-in-avro-schema",ConsumedWith(myKeySerde,myValueSerde)); 

KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(),properties);
streams.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to generate a random ConsumerGroup every time you start the stream application. Something like:

```java
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, GROUP_ID + currentTimestamp);
```

That way, the stream will start reading from "earliest" as you have set it already in `auto.offset.reset`.

By the way, you are setting the properties for `group.id` twice in your code...

Comment: Thanks mike for the suggestions. It did not worked unfortunately. I tried for both group id as well as for applicaiton id

Answer (score 0):

It will help someone who is also facing same issue. Replace Application Id and Group Id with some unique identifier using UUID.randomId.toString() in the configuration property. It should fetch the messages from beginning